# Javascript aws lambda unexplained behaviour

Tags: javascript, aws-cdk

In the following example, the lambda code works (the lambda factory class), but the api code does not. Any idea why that might be? The lambda code instantiates the expected outputs. But the API code creaates nothing. It doesn't fail. It just doesn't do anything... As a quick sanity check, I instantiated the same chunk of code in the main file, and that does work fine...

**top level**

```
import { LambdaFactory } from './factory-dev/lambda/lambda-factory';
import { ApiGatewayFactory2 } from './factory-dev/api-gateway/apiGW';

export class SnDevStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


// 1. Lambda
    const lambdaFactory = new LambdaFactory(this, 'lambdaFactoryId');
    const lambdaSigfoxSync = lambdaFactory.sigfoxSync('testing options');

// 2. Dev API
    const apiGatewayFactory = new ApiGatewayFactory2(this, 'ApiGatewayFactoryId');
    const api = apiGatewayFactory.getApi('testing options');
}
```

**lambda factory class**

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';                // need for Runtime
import * as lambda_nodejs from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';

export class LambdaFactory extends cdk.Construct {
  constructor (scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id);
  }
  
  private TAG:string = "sn-dev-";

  public sigfoxSync(options: string): lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction {
    const testLambda = new lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'sigfox-sync', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      entry: 'lambda/sn-dev/sigfox-sync.js',
      handler: 'handler',
      functionName: this.TAG + 'sigfox-sync',
      description: 'Get all devices from Sigfox API & Sync into dynamoDB.',
      memorySize: 256,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(720)
    });
    return testLambda;
  }

}
```

**api factory class**

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as apiGateway from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway';


export class ApiGatewayFactory2 extends cdk.Stack {


  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id);
  }

  public getApi(options: string):apiGateway.RestApi {
    const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, 'sn-dev', 
    { 
      restApiName: 'sn-dev',
      deploy: true,
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowOrigins: apiGateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
        allowMethods: apiGateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS // this is also the default
      },
    });
    return api;
  }
}
```

To double check, the following works perfectly if I write it directly in the main file. Why on earth does it not work in the factory class????

```
const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, 'sn-dev', 
{ 
  restApiName: 'sn-dev',
  deploy: true,
  deployOptions: {
    // documentationVersion: documentVersion
  },
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: apiGateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    allowMethods: apiGateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS // this is also the default
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ApiGatewayFactory2` is extending `Stack` it should extend `Construct`.

I think if you want to create a child stack you need to extend `NestedStack`.